# How to write Case Statement SAPui5

Tags: sapui5, case

I have to check, when the User is selecting a `DocumentNumber` if it is an Order or a Notification. Therefor my `OData` is giving me the `DocumentType` "AUFK" or "QMEL". So if he select an "AUFK" there should appear a PopUp with some Data and when he select an "Qmel" there should appear another PopUp.

So in the OData ('MultiInfoSet') I get the Data for the Different DocumentTypes (AUFK and Qmel) but I don't know how to write these Statement.

```
onNumberPress: function (oEvent) {
    //try {
    var oItem = oEvent.getSource("order");
    var sPath = oItem.getBindingContext('MultiInfoSet').getPath();
    var sTitle = _oController.getModel('MultiInfoSet').getProperty(sPath + "/DocumentNumber");
    // Prüfen auf QMEL oder AUFK
    if ;
        //wenn QMEL
        //wenn AUFK
```

Comment: just a suggestion: sapui5 is just a javascript framework. Your question isn't really related to sapui5, but to javascript itself. You'll get more responses by tagging the question that way. And you'll find more information looking for generic javascript syntax as opposed to sapui5.

Comment: Please change your german comments into english. It relates to your question.

Comment: Uhh sry but I already got a Solution thx for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you just need the correct syntax? [Have a look here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

```
switch(sTitle) {
  case "AUFK":
    alert("AUFK");
    break;
  case "QMEL":
    alert("QMEL");
    break;
  default:
    alert("unknown");
}
```